# Stylish Class to write a Book in LaTeX?

Tags: document-classes, book-design

I want to write a book in LaTeX, but not in the conventional way. I want some good fonts and better page layout.

The following link is an example of what I want:
http://www.intechopen.com/books/advances-in-biomaterials-science-and-biomedical-applications

If anyone can suggest me a similar kind of template, I'll be grateful to that one.

Kindly suggest alternatives.

Comment: Hello, Ashish. On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: In addition: The MWE doesn’t have to be perfect. Show what you‘ve achieved until now in your attempt for a solution. And a screenshot would be better. Since you do not have the right for posting images: Add it as link (remove the exclamation mark in front of the link), a user with enough reputation will convert it for you.

Comment: Have a look at the `tufte-book`class, it provides a fancy layout following the books of E. Tufte.

Comment: Or, if you don't like Tufte, try `memoir`

Comment: @Ipsen : According to the PDF properties, it has not only Palatino, but also Courier, Frutiger, Arial, Helvetica, Calibri, and Times Roman. But no  Comic Sans...